# I am trying to add some missing settings to WooCommerce countries

Tags: php, woocommerce

On my webshop checkout I am trying to adjust some country settings that are missing in the default WC country locales. There are several countries I want to change but I am trying now with one (Aruba - AW). For instance for AW I want to make zipcode not required and hidden and I want to change the label of state to "District"

I am trying with the following code in functions.php but I keep getting a 503 error.

````
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_country_locale', 'wp_hcwa_woocommerce_get_country_locale_filter' );

/**
 * Function for `woocommerce_get_country_locale` filter-hook.
 *
 * @param  $array
 *
 * @return
 */
function wp_hcwa_woocommerce_get_country_locale_filter( $array ){
  $array = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_country_locale', array(
                 'AW' => array(
                  'postcode' => array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'hidden' => true,
                    ),
                  'state' => array(
                    'label'       => __( 'District', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'required' => false,
                  ),
              ),
          )
        );
    return $array;
}```

what am I doing wrong??

I expect the checkout to hide the zipcode field and change State to District when I choose Aruba from the dropdown
````

Comment: Can you share the error message that you receive?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_country_locale', 'my_hcwa_get_country_locale_filter' );

function my_hcwa_get_country_locale_filter( $fields ) {
    // Aruba
    $fields['AW']['state']['label'] = __( 'Region', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['AW']['postcode']['required'] = false;
    $fields['AW']['postcode']['hidden'] = true;

    // Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba
    $fields['BQ']['state']['label'] = __( 'Island', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['BQ']['postcode']['required'] = false;
    $fields['BQ']['postcode']['hidden'] = true;

    // Suriname
    $fields['SR']['state']['label'] = __( 'District', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['SR']['postcode']['required'] = false;
    $fields['SR']['postcode']['hidden'] = true;

    // Guyana
    $fields['GY']['state']['label'] = __( 'Region', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['GY']['postcode']['required'] = false;
    $fields['GY']['postcode']['hidden'] = true;

    // Curacao
    $fields['CW']['state']['label'] = __( 'Town', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['CW']['postcode']['required'] = false;
    $fields['CW']['postcode']['hidden'] = true;

    // Dutch Saint Martin
    $fields['SX']['state']['label'] = __( 'Town', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['SX']['postcode']['required'] = false;
    $fields['SX']['postcode']['hidden'] = true;

    return $fields;
}
```